# Copying large amounts of data from S3 to ElasticSearch

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, kibana

I have access to an S3 bucket containing traffic data from a website. All of this data is stored in JSON files with one object per line. On average these files contain about 20,000 different JSON objects. The bucket stores 100-200 of these 30-40 MB files per hour depending on the amount of traffic to the site, so it's on the order of 2-4 million records per hour.

I need to copy this data into ElasticSearch to create data visualizations in Kibana. I'm currently using the Bulk API from Elastic and jq to format the JSON for the Bulk request (Adding the indexing so ElasticSearch indexes it properly) This is very slow. One 20,000 record file takes close to two minutes to download from S3, reformat with jq, and push to ElasticSearch using my Java code, the AWS Java SDK, and Elastic Bulk API.

I have already considered using AWS Lambda, but I cannot connect a Lambda function from my account to the S3 bucket of another account. Any other ideas on how to upload this much data to ElasticSearch?

Comment: Is your ES cluster also hosted on Amazon by any chance?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's on a separate corporate/conduit account from the S3 bucket.

Comment: Have you tried running your Java code directly on an AWS server? You'd already spare a lot of time just for the download of the data.

Comment: Well I'm downloading the data because it has to be decrypted and unzipped. I don't have write access to the bucket, only read/get, so I'd still have to store the decrypted files somewhere before pushing them to ES.

Comment: Yes, but you'd be better off doing all that on some host that is already in the AWS cloud. That way you'd benefit from their big pipes for moving data around. You could spin up an instance for a few minutes, run your Java code and then kill it. Note that I'm just shooting in the wild here, but it looks to me that the pipe size is your main issue, i.e. having to download GB of data on your localhost in order to re-upload it after transforming it sounds like what is killing the performance.

Comment: I'll work on setting that up tomorrow and see how it goes. In the meantime, is there a more efficient means of processing and uploading that amount of data to ES outside of the Bulk API? If you're available for questions, would you like to move this to chat?

Comment: The bulk API is definitely the way to go if you have massive amount of data to index. Definitely open to chat about it.

Comment: Does the amount of records in the request affect the speed? Example: 20000 records per file. Does it matter if I do 4 requests of 5000, 2 of 10000, 1 of 20000, etc.? I'm doing all 20k in one curl post request.

Comment: Yes, [that definitely has an impact](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html#_using_and_sizing_bulk_requests), you should try different sizes and see which ones works best with your pipe size and ES tuning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your S3 bucket and Elastic search cluster are not part of the same VPC or in different private networks.
To allow connection to both services you need to do some AWS networking. Enable [VPC peering](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html) if your account are in different VPC or setup a [NAT gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) to allow traffic to pass between two networks.
The last possibility is to enable [cross account permission to lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-create-x-account-permissions.html).